# Cabal don't find relative library for compilation of gsasl package

Tags: haskell, shared-libraries, cabal, cabal-install

I'm using Haskell on webfaction server, with non root access, on a CentOS 6 system.

I have a `/lib/` folder which contain libraries.

Actually, i have a problem with some libraries needed for an installation of package using `cabal install`.

I need the `libgsasl` library installed, so i download and compile the [gsasl](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/#downloading) package from sources :

- I wget the latest tar.gz [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsasl/#downloading)
- I run `./configure --prefix=$HOME` to install compiled libraries into `$HOME/lib`
- i `make` and `make install`

Next, i try two way with `cabal install gsasl` command, which actually fails :

- `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`
- `cabal install gsasl --bindir=$HOME/bin --extra-include-dirs=/home/reyman64/lib/ --extra-lib-dirs=/home/reyman64/lib`

Any of the command found the good libraries ...

```
The pkg-config package 'libgsasl' version superior to 1.1 is required but it could not be found.
```

So i verify, my version is 1.8, and i have the libgsasl.sa .la .so .so.7 .so.7.9.6 in `$HOME/lib` and i have a `libgsasl.pc` into `$home/lib/pkgconfig`

Any idea of the problem  ?

Comment: What is your value of your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable?

Comment: Value is not set, perhaps it's that ?

Comment: It's that, thanks @erikR. Perhaps you want to create an answer with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable is set to include `$HOME/lib/pkgconfig`, i.e. the directory where you've placed `libgsasl.pc`.

Comment: I try to make a complete tutorial for haskell on webfaction here now : https://community.webfaction.com/questions/19167/install-haskell-ghc-and-cabal-from-source-on-webfaction